# Struts and nested logic:iterate tag

Tags: java, struts

In Struts environment I have a bean, in that bean I have a matrix called `beans_e`, inside the view I can write usual array info in this way:

```
<bean:write name="ReportForm" property="beans_e" />
```

What I want now, is to iterate this matrix printing every element inside table's cell. I have take a look to `logic:iterate` tag, but, as far as I know, this tag doesn't works with matrix. How can I handle this issue?

Best regards

Comment: What exactly is the "matrix" in beans_e? What kind of object is it?

Comment: String[][]. 
With: 
`<logic:iterate id="row" name="ReportForm" property="beans_e" type="java.lang.String[]" indexId="count_r"><%= row %>
</logic:iterate>`
I can print the object info of every row. How I have to create the second iterator?

Comment: Good to hear you found the solution. btw if you found the answer that is working, please make that information as answer instead of publishing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**, using `nested:iterate` tag rather than `logic:iterate`.

```
<nested:iterate id="row" name="ReportForm" property="beans_e">
  <nested:iterate id="field" name="row">
    <%= field %>
  </nested:iterate>
</nested:iterate>
```