# Struts logic:iterate over list of lists

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am trying to iterate over a class that has another class as a member variable. Here is some code from the class:

```
public class UnregisteredCaseRecipient extends Auditable {

private String peoplePin;
private String recipName;
private String roleCd;
private String secLvl;
private List<UnregisteredCaseRecipientNotification> unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications;
```

The JSP code that I have tried is the following:

```
                        <logic:iterate name="caseRecip" id="unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications">
                                <td style="width: 25px;">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="docRecipNotify" id="docRecipNotify" value="${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications.id}" ${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications.notificationCheck}/>
                                </td>
                        </logic:iterate>
```

I have tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843156/struts-and-nested-logiciterate-tag) with no luck.

```
<nested:iterate id="unregisteredRecipients" name="crFilingServiceListForm" property="unregisteredCaseRecipients" >
                                    <nested:iterate id="unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications" name="unregisteredRecipients">
                                        <td style="width: 25px;">notify: ${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications.notify} id: ${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications.id}
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="docRecipNotify" id="docRecipNotify" value="${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications.id}" ${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications.notificationCheck}/>
                                        </td>
                                    </nested:iterate>   
                                </nested:iterate>
```

And I also tried something like [this](http://technology.amis.nl/2004/08/25/multiple-level-nesting-with-code-logiciteratecode-in-struts/) to with no luck.

```
                        <logic:iterate name="crFilingServiceListForm" property="${caseRecip.unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications" id="caseRecipNotify" indexId="j">
                                <td style="width: 25px;">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="docRecipNotify" id="docRecipNotify" value="${caseRecipNotify.id}" ${caseRecipNotify.notificationCheck}/>
                                </td>
                        </logic:iterate>
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: Option 1 gets the following error: "javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create iterator for this collection"  Option 2 has no error but the fields are blank. Option 3 gets 500 error with the following message: "OracleJSP: An error occurred. Consult your application/system administrator for support. Programmers should consider setting the init-param debug_mode to "true" to see the complete exception message."  Thanks @CPU100 for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using a nested for instead:

```
<c:forEach items="${crFilingServiceListForm.unregisteredCaseRecipients}" var="unregisteredRecip">
    <c:forEach items="${unregisteredRecip.unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications}" var="unregisteredNotification">
    <td style="width: 25px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="docRecipNotify" id="docRecipNotify" value="${unregisteredNotification.id}" ${unregisteredNotification.notificationCheck}/>
    </td>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks for your help everyone!

Tom

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<logic:iterate name="unregisteredCaseRecipientList" id="unregisteredCaseRecipient">
    <logic:iterate name="unregisteredCaseRecipient" property="unregisteredCaseRecipientNotifications" id="unregisteredCaseRecipientNotification">
        <td style="width: 25px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="docRecipNotify" id="docRecipNotify" value="${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotification.id}" ${unregisteredCaseRecipientNotification.notificationCheck}/>
        </td>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:iterate>
```

Otherwise you can use `<bean:write/>` instead of ${}

Good Luck!

Comment: When I try this I get "500 Internal Server Error

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean unregisteredCaseRecipientList in any scope
 at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.lookup(TagUtils.java:992)
 at org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.IterateTag.doStartTag(IterateTag.java:234)" Thanks @jvazquez

Comment: You have to put it into a scope, such as request. For example    request.setAttribute("unregisteredCaseRecipientList", myList);

Comment: @jvazquez if you write a set attribute, ur sublist doesnt work fine, because you will have toc reate many sublist a list items in ur scope